# How to make div resize on window size without losing its float?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, css-float

I have a comments block where every comment consists basically of 2 divs: 
avatar (float:left, fixed with) and comment_text (relative width).

http://cssdesk.com/YwgA2

I have a problem with resizing browser window. On resize, the first thing that happens - right div goes down. Only when it is under first div, it starts resizing.

I want it comment_text div resize to min-size before it goes under floated div.

How would i do that?

Comment: modify these style declaration in .comment_text

remove display
give margin-left:110px;

Comment: for arrow give top in px

Comment: Wondering whether the answer helped or not..

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the width for `.comment_text`. set

```
width: calc(100% - 110px); // 100px for the avatars width and 10 to compensate margins
```

You might as well want to set a `min-width` too.

check this: http://cssdesk.com/rzkaF